# Jerky animation when moving an object along a Bézier curve (no plugins)

Tags: actionscript-3, math, language-agnostic, bezier

I am using [Loom SDK](https://www.loomsdk.com/) for my current project - its syntax is a mix between AS3 and .NET. I am trying to move an object along a Bézier curve (I can't use Greensock or such, as it is not available for Loom).

Here's the code:

```
public override function onFrame(): void    {

        var t:Number = ( Platform.getTime() - _startTime) / _duration;

        if (t < 1) {
            var newPos = curveBetweenTwoPoint(_start, _dest, _bezier, t);
            _entity.x = newPos.x;
            _entity.y = newPos.y;
        } else {
            // finished!
            if (_finishCallback != null) {
                _finishCallback();
            }
        }
    }

public function curveBetweenTwoPoint(start:Point, dest:Point, bezier:Point, t:Number) : Point {
        var x:Number = (  (1-t)*(1-t)*start.x + 2*(1-t)*t*bezier.x+t*t*dest.x);
        var y:Number = (  (1-t)*(1-t)*start.y + 2*(1-t)*t*bezier.y+t*t*dest.y);

        return new Point(x, y);
    }
```

This basically interpolates the (x,y) coordinate of an object over time. However, once duration gets smaller than 1 second, the animation is very jerky - I suspect it is because that `Platform.getTime()` doesn't return the current clock time with enough precision.

Is there any way I can improve my code?

Comment: I'm guessing `onFrame` occurs every time a new frame is about to be drawn. Perhaps instead of using clock time to calculate `t`, you could use (number of frames elapsed)/(total number of frames the movement should take)

Comment: What is `stage.frameRate` set to? Jerky animations are common when set to the default 24. Set it to 30+ (maxes out at 60) and see if that helps. Note that the higher the framerate, the less time your code has to run. It's important to find a good compromise